# Eclipse CDT complains about unresolved functions but still builds successfully

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

The following C++ application compiles and runs successfully within Eclipse CDT but the IDE is still reporting an error stating:

```
Could not resolve function wprintf
```

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main()
{
  wprintf(L"Hello world");
  return 0;
}
```

The directory `/usr/include` (where `wchar.h` resides) is definitely listed within the Include path as otherwise the application would not compile. Hitting F3 on `wprintf` reports:

```
Could not find symbol 'wprintf' in index
```

This is my set up:

- openSUSE 11.4
- Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Indigo Service Release 2 - Build 20120216-1857)
- Eclipse CDT v8.0.2.201202111925

Does anyone know how I can get Eclipse CDT to resolve this function correctly?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with my Juno Release, Build id: 20120510-1218 on Fedora 14. To solve the index problem: Navigate to preferences -> c/c++ -> Editor -> Indexer ->  uncheck "Allow heuristic resolution of includes"

-All the best

Answer (score 3):

At preferences -> c/c++ -> Editor -> Indexer disable indexer, apply, go back to preferences, and enable index again. This makes Eclipse to re-index the workspace. After that, my false red signs on the right side of the editor were gone.

Answer (score 0):

> The directory /usr/include (where wchar.h resides) is definitely
>   listed within the Include path as otherwise the application would not
>   compile

I guess this directory is listed only in *compiler* Include path. This directory has to be listed in *Eclipse C++ parser* [Include path](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_prop_general_pns_inc.htm) as well, to resolve functions correctly.

Comment: I've checked and `/usr/include` is listed within the Include directories for both GNU C and GNU C++.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if /usr/include is listed correctly, then go to `preferences -> c/c++ -> Editor -> Indexer -> select Indexer`

Sometimes change it from fast c/c++ indexer to the Full one resolves the problem.

Hope it helps

Comment: strange, I use the same CDT version, but don't have these options, only `C/C++ -> Indexer - enable indexer` (but no way to select full or otherwise), and no `indexer` category in `C/C++ -> Editor`

Answer (score 0):

what helped me was
on the jni folder press the right mouse button
properties > c/c++ general > paths and symbols
add the same paths as in 
project > properties c/c++ general > paths and symbols

hope it helps